# Holomorphic locally trivial fibrations over the puctured disk

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, and assume that I have a holomorphic locally trivial fibration $X \to \mathbb{C}^\times$. How does the complex orientation affect the possibilities for the structure of the fibration? In particular, suppose that the fiber is $F = \mathbb{C}^N$ or even $F = \mathbb{C}^\times \times \mathbb{C}^N$. Can we guarantee that the fibration is trivial?

If the question about the fibration is too strong, then maybe we can say something about the local systems defined by the fibration. In the examples above, $\underline{H^0(F, \mathbb{Q})}$ is certainly trivial, but does the orientability guarantee that $\underline{H^1(\mathbb{C}^\times \times \mathbb{C}^N, \mathbb{Q})}$ is trivial?

I would also like to know some reference where I can read more about this, because all of my search about fibre bundles end up giving more results about vector bundles than fibre bundles.

Answer (score 1):

Let the fiber be $F = \mathbb{C}^\times$, and consider the map $F \to F: z \mapsto 1/z$. This induces in cohomology the morphism $-id: H^1(F) \to H^1(F)$. Therefore, if we consider the complex variety
$$ X := (\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}^\times) / \sim, \qquad (r, \theta, z) \sim (r, \theta + 2 \pi, 1/z) $$
together with the morphism $X \to \mathbb{C}^\times: (r, \theta, z) \mapsto r e^{i \theta}$, we have an example of a holomorphic locally trivial fibration such that $\underline{H^1(F)}$ is not trivial.

(Intuitively we are considering the universal cover of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ and gluing the fibers with the map $z \mapsto 1/z$ when we turn once around the origin. This can easily be checked to be a complex manifold)